# flash builder 4.6 pass variable from application to item renderer

Tags: variables, flash-builder, itemrenderer

I'm trying to pass a variable from my main application to an itemRenderer. I know that, when using a Custom Component, you can just public declare a variable and you can access this variable from the main application and pass it through to the component, but with itemRenderers this doesn't seem to work.

I can't seem to find the exact thing I'm trying to do on the Adobe forums or on this site. Does anyone of you know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are trying to do, but in your main application file, you can declare a public variable and access it in the item renderer using `this.parentApplication.myVariable`. I do this all the time, including in item renderers, to determine whether the user is on a tablet or phone.

Ex: `myComponent.setStyle("fontSize", this.parentApplication.isTablet ? 18 : 16);`

Comment: I'm now using an itemRendererFunction and that seems to do the trick. I choose another renderer based upon the variable, which has only two possibilities, so this works this time. I'll remember your tip, and try it out too! Seems a little easier and cleaner than my solution. Thanks!